# Loading templates with underscore gives error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I have a requirejs webapp which loads a lot of libraries (it is rather complicated to jsfiddle the loading). The bottom point though is:

```
console.log(_.VERSION);
_.template("<p>");
```

In the underscorejs site with the dev console this results in : 1.7.0 and the second line returns a function.

In my site after loading

the version reported is the same. 
the second line reads Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

This creates a problem when I try to load the templates in my BackBone Views

stacktrace:

```
(anonymous function)VM2739:762 InjectedScript._evaluateOnVM2739:695 InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrapVM2739:609 InjectedScript.evaluate
```

I don't have a library that includes underscore. I am not sure if it is important to show how the requirejs loads _ because the end result is that the correct version is loaded..?

At the time of writing I have spent a considerable amount of time changing all parts of my code with no effect.

I have google the message "string is not a function" and I found some references that it means there is some kind of conflict.

Comment: Prost more code. It sounds like you are rendering the template (calling the generated function)

Comment: @mu this is the total code. I run this in the console. It happens after I load up my application with requirejs. of course it happens in other parts of the application but this is the easiest to reproduce. The code is similar I just do var x=_.template("<html">) and same thing happens.

Comment: my application is huge like 25 AMD and non libs and many js scripts (over 100) .how can I reproduce this in jsfiddle? I will try to find something more to show here

Comment: Create a fiddle that only loads underscore and your template via require and reproduces the error. You'll probably figure out the answer in the meantime!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in all of the hundreds of views that I was loading up with requirejs and underscore, this cryptic message was the consequence of this line

```
template: _.template=require("text!TemplateMapView"),
```

that was replaced with this line..

```
template: _.template(require("text!TemplateMapView"))
```

this overwrote the function with a string. requirejs loaded randomly the views and everytime a different script (the directly loaded after this one) produced an error. that was very confusing.

Comment: downvoting an answer that solves the problem makes the site worse.

Comment: If we had a question and an answer for all the possible wild typos all JS programmers in the world have done in their life, this site would become the first realisation ever of the Library of Babel. Imho the best thing you could do with this question is to delete it altogether.

Comment: seeing a very weird and non-descriptive error message that has nothing to do with a typo could be helpful to programmers and that's why i still keep it.I don't mind punishment the site is harsh enough

Comment: "very weird and non-descriptive error message that has nothing to do with its real cause": that's basically the heart of JavaScript and we all got to love it regardless. Combinations of possible causes and unrelated error messages are virtually infinite. JL Borges is the visionary that in the '40s saw JS coming :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most propably, requireJS is injecting the **raw string value** of the template in your module, and you think it's injecting the compiled template function.

You are trying to access this as a **function**, which results in the `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function` error.

You need to feed this template string into `_.template()`.